# Spark: Selecting only specific partitions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a huge table in my RDBMS database which contains different account types of records.
I load this data into spark once and would be looping over this table several times based on account types to generate some reports.

I have created a Temporary Global view on this table.

```
df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("account_tbl")
```

Now, I would like to partition this view into multiple partitions based on account_type column where data is divided into chunks so each time I loop over this view for an account_type I want to select only that particular partition.

Can repartition on that specific column resolve this easily? If yes, should I need to repartition the df and then create a global temporary view or I'm not sure on this. 
And also, how do I ensure that only that specific partition is getting selected each time I loop. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.repartition(partition_size, col("account_type"))` for example. Here I set both partition size and the column I want to partition by. Otherwise in the case you want to use Spark SQL you can use:

```
SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = partition_size
SELECT * FROM df CLUSTER BY account_type
```

`CLUSTER BY` works similarly to repartition but it will also sort your dataframe.

To access the data within each partition by using similar code to the next one:

```
df.foreachPartition {
      p => /*your code goes here*/
}
```

Within you can do all your calculations and generate the reports you need.

To estimate partition size you can start with default values eg:200 and if you get Out Of Memory exception during shuffling you can increase the number of partitions eg 1024 until your job executes successfully. There is no standard way to calculate exact number of partitions since it depends on several factors such as size of your cluster (available cores, memory) and the data size.

Also, there is no way to determine what data your partition will contain since the RDDs are distributed randomly among the cluster. The only way to determine that is with a custom filter inside foreachPartition. For instance you could apply a custom condition as next:

```
df.foreachPartition( iter => {
        iter.foreach { i =>
          if(i.some_column == "somevalue")
            //write populate data

        }
    })
```

Good luck

Comment: @@Alexandros, thanks for your reply.
Just few things, I can do either SparkSQL or Repartitioning.
1. In either case, how do I determine the partition_size?
2. How do I validate that only that partition is selected?
3. Once repartitioned, I also need to join with other dataframes. 
So I don't know how to proceed with foreachPartition option?

Please advice

Comment: @@Alexandros, thanks for the prompt response. upvoted :)

Comment: thank you @1pluszara :) I am curius to see if this will work for you. Please let me know if you made it work